# How can I make an automator service always show up?

Tags: automator, services

I have an AppleScript that adds the subject of a selected email in Mail to my task manager.

I have put this AppleScript in an Automator service so I can hotkey it.

Only problem is this: Lion insists on only showing the service when I have text selected. Somehow OS X thinks its a text based script even though I specified there is no input.

Is there any way to have the service show up in the services menu independent of the selection I have?

Answer (score 4):

In Automator at the very top of your workflow, there is a dropdown box for which the prompt reads **Service receives selected**. If you are getting the results you report, the word **text** likely appears in the dropdown box. Change it to **no input** and save the service.

[image]